# calling copy constructor with uniform initialization

Tags: c++11, g++4.8

Im trying to call default copy constructor with uniform initialization, but it's not working.

For example:

```
#include <string>

struct Work {
        std::string author;
        std::string name;
        int year;
};

int main() {
        Work s9 {"Beethoven", "Symphony No. 9 in D minor, Op. 125; Choral", 1824}; // memberwise initialization
        Work currently_playing {s9};    // copy initialization

        return 0;
}
```

Im compiling it as: `g++ -std=c++11 -c Ex1.cpp`

And compiler gives error:

```
Ex1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Ex1.cpp:11:28: error: could not convert ‘s9’ from ‘Work’ to ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’
  Work currently_playing {s9}; // copy initialization
                            ^
```

Doesn't uniform initialization work to copy initialize object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the C++11 standard. C++14 changed how *list-initialization* is performed. In C++11, `X{X{}}` would perform *aggregate-initialization* if `X` is an [aggregate type](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#def:aggregate). C++14 added an extra clause so that this code correctly invokes the corresponding constructor; [dcl.init.list]/3.2:

> If T is an aggregate class and the initializer list has a single
>   element of type cv U, where U is T or a class derived from T, the
>   object is initialized from that element (by copy-initialization for
>   copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for
>   direct-list-initialization).

Sources:

http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.2

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Explanation

Answer (score 2):

This is either an old g++ bug or an old core language defect. Your code compiles properly starting from g++ 5. I strongly suggest you to update your compiler, as 4.8 is extremely old.

[**conformance view on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/wh1qAp)

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iVqGPUqVdeg9QY50)

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I thought so, because it works in msvc.